# Access Gmail atom feed using OAuth

Tags: python, oauth, gmail, gdata

I'm trying to grab the [Gmail atom feed](https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/unread/) from a python application using OAuth. I have a working application that downloads the Google Reader feed, and I think it *should* simply be a matter of changing the scope and feed URLs. After replacing the URLs I can still successfully get Request and Access tokens, but when I try to grab the feed using the Access token I get a "401 Unauthorized" error. Here's my simple test program:

```
import urlparse
import oauth2 as oauth

scope = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/"
sub_url = scope + "unread"

request_token_url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=%s&xoauth_displayname=%s" % (scope, "Test Application")
authorize_url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken'
access_token_url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken'

oauth_key = "anonymous"
oauth_secret = "anonymous"

consumer = oauth.Consumer(oauth_key, oauth_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

# Get a request token.
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
request_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))

print "Request Token:"
print "    - oauth_token        = %s" % request_token['oauth_token']
print "    - oauth_token_secret = %s" % request_token['oauth_token_secret']
print

# Step 2: Link to web page where the user can approve the request token.
print "Go to the following link in your browser:"
print "%s?oauth_token=%s" % (authorize_url, request_token['oauth_token'])
print

raw_input('Press enter after authorizing.')

# Step 3: Get access token using approved request token
token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'], request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "POST")
access_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))

print "Access Token:"
print "    - oauth_token        = %s" % access_token['oauth_token']
print "    - oauth_token_secret = %s" % access_token['oauth_token_secret']
print

# Access content using access token
token = oauth.Token(access_token['oauth_token'], access_token['oauth_token_secret'])
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

resp, content = client.request(sub_url, 'GET')
print content
```

You'll notice that I'm using 'anonymous/anonymous' as my OAuth key/secret, as mentioned in the [Google documents for unregistered applications](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#SigningOAuth). This works fine for google reader, so I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work for Gmail. Does anyone have any idea on why this might not work, or how I could go about troubleshooting it? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you are implementing this yourself? Check out http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/. Anyway this isn't an answer to your question so here it is in a comment!

Comment: @alecwh: libgmail seems to require that my program know the user's username and password. I'm trying to avoid that if I can, which is why  I want to use oauth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try accessing Google's IMAP servers with OAuth instead of using the ATOM feed. After a little googling I found [this](http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2):

> "Gmail supports OAuth over IMAP and
>   SMTP via a standard they call XOAUTH.
>   This allows you to authenticate
>   against Gmail's IMAP and SMTP servers
>   using an OAuth token and secret. It
>   also has the added benefit of allowing
>   you to use vanilla SMTP and IMAP
>   libraries. The python-oauth2 package
>   provides both IMAP and SMTP libraries
>   that implement XOAUTH and wrap
>   imaplib.IMAP4_SSL and smtplib.SMTP.
>   This allows you to connect to Gmail
>   with OAuth credentials using standard
>   Python libraries."

from  http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

Comment: Thanks. This looks like what I need. I'm not sure why the gmail feed  isn't working, but afaict it seems to be second-class citizen in the gdata APIs anyway.